# How to set path of file in Open dialog WinAPI C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I wonder how can I set a file path in the Open Dialog, that was started by another process. 
I mean this dialog

[image]

I need to set path to file.

What is the best way to do this ?

Of course I can always send keys using `SendInput` but is there any more elegant way to do this ? For example to send WM_COMMAND or something else ?

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Before anyone can give you good advice, I think you need to explain why you want to operate on a dialog owned by another process.

Comment: Have a look at [UI automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking can only be solved with hacks.

The best approach is to use [MSAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Active_Accessibility)/[UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) as much as possible.

Assuming you know the HWND of the Open dialog you can [walk all the child items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317975(v=vs.85).aspx) looking for something with the role of ROLE_SYSTEM_COMBOBOX. Inside this item you need to find something with the role of ROLE_SYSTEM_TEXT that is editable (enabled and visible). Just looking for a ROLE_SYSTEM_TEXT item might find the search box in the top right corner.

If you can't find this object then it might be the older style dialog, restart the search and only look for ROLE_SYSTEM_TEXT.

It might be a good idea to verify this detection by comparing the HWNDs id (I will discuss these later).

When you find the item you can change the text with `put_accValue()`.

There is also a [`CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646855(v=vs.85).aspx) message but you need to be inside the process to use it.

---

If you don't know the HWND of the dialog or want to do this to all open dialogs on the system then you need a [hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) so you know when there is a new HWND candidate. Detecting these can be tricky.

The only option I know is to look for certain controls with certain ids. In particular there will be [a ListBox with the id of `lst1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960(v=vs.85).aspx) and either a Edit box or a Combo box with a specific id.

You need to do a lot of testing to get this right. Remember that on Vista and later there are two dialog implementations (`IFileOpenDialog` and `GetOpenFileName`) and you need to test both. `GetOpenFileName` even has a old and a new mode (compatibility mode when old applications use templates and/or hooks).